# From double to geopoint remove me the ,

Tags: java, android, casting, double, geopositioning

i have 2 doubles, lat and long with the form (X.XXXXXX).
I'm trying to make new GeoPoint from this values, but when I convert to GeoPoint, remove the `,` obtain this result `geopoint(XXXX,XXXX);`

```
Double latitudEditando = Double.parseDouble(datosLugar.get(4).toString());  
Double longitudEditando = Double.parseDouble(datosLugar.get(5).toString());   
puntoEditando = new GeoPoint((int)(latitudEditando*1e6), (int)(longitudEditando*1e6));
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
datosLugar.get(4) return me: 40.3138987 (Double) 
datosLugar.get(5) return me: -3.8811184 (double)
 puntoEditando return me (403138987,-38811184)
```

Sorry, thats OK, i think geopoint there is (40,00000 , 44,000)

Comment: What data type is `datosLugar`? What do `datosLugar.get(4)` and `datosLugar.get(5)` look like?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` what are you expecting?

Comment: What makes you think you're doing something wrong? In other words, we don't know what isn't working.

Comment: datosLugar.get(4) return me: 40.3138987 (Double)
datosLugar.get(5) return me: -3.8811184  (double)
puntoEditando return me (403138987,-38811184)

Comment: Sorry, thats OK, i think geopoint must be (3,0000 , 4,00000)

Comment: Well you cast them to int after you multiply by 1e6 so what you are getting is reasonable

Answer (score 0):

The [`GeoPoint`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) class from the google addons is constructed with latitude and longitude as microdegrees in the form of a `int`. This is fine as long as `latitudEditando` and `longitudEditando` are doubles that express coordinates in degrees:

```
new GeoPoint((int)(latitudEditando*1e6), (int)(longitudEditando*1e6));
```